# how editor.autoClosingOvertype works in vscode settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

can anyone show me how editor.autoClosingOvertype works in vscode settings? thank you very much

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overtype mode** allows you to type the SAME character as the next character and NOT have that same character added again but act as if you typed the same character on top of that already existing character.

It is used by people who want to keep their hands on the keyboard and simply type the next character to get PAST it.  It can be much faster to simply type the next character if you want to get past it (rather than right-arrowing past it) but you don't want two of those characters.

In this case you asked about overtyping and the `editor.autoClosingOvertype` which applies to quotes or brackets.  There are three options for that setting.

`never` means when you type the quote or closing bracket (when you are right before it) - it is NOT typed over and another quote or closing bracket is simply added where you typed it.

`always` means always overtype that next closing quote or bracket no matter how it might have been inserted in the first place.  Sometimes those quotes/brackets were added automatically by the vscode language server and sometimes by another method (like a snippet).

`auto` - the default will overtype that next closing quote or bracket only when it was automatically added by the vscode language server and not when it was added by any other means.